# Aplicación que pida numero entre 1 y 10 y muestre la tabla de multiplicar JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy empezando a programar en Java y no sé cómo decirle que si no introduce un número entre el 1 y el 10, tenga que volver a introducirlo.

Este es el enunciado:

> Crea una aplicación que pida un numero entre el 1 y el 10 y muestre la tabla de multiplicar de dicho numero.
>
> Si el usuario introduce un numero que no este entre el 1 y el 10 debe volver a preguntar.

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
            
System.out.println("Introduzca un numero entero: ");

int numero=sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Tabla del "+ numero);

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {                
    System.out.println(numero+ " * " +i+ " = "+ numero*i);
}
```

No se como hacer que me vuelva a mostrar *"introduzca un número"* si elijo un número que no esta entre el 1 y el 10.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: no se como añadir que me vuelva a mostrar (introduzca un numero) si elijo un numero que no esta entre el 1 y el 10

Comment: Con un `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que meter la petición de datos en un bucle y no salir de él hasta que el número no sea de tu agrado. Algo como esto:

```
int numero = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Introduzca un numero entero: ");
        
    numero=sc.nextInt();

} while( numero < 1 || numero > 10);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, claro si yo por ejemplo pusiera un while en vez de un do while, al ser la condicion falsa desde el principio pasaria del bucle mientras que con el do while me aseguro que al menos lo lea una vez. ¿Seria mas o menos asi?

Comment: sí, así te aseguras al menos una vez, salvo que el while le pongas una condición con una inicialización que la primera vez siempre entre... Eso ya como te guste más.

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, márcala como aceptada. Gracias!

Comment: Perdon, es la primera vez que formulo una pregunta en stack overflow. Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo usando un while, se volvera a mostrar que introduzcas el numero si este no esta comprendido entre 1 y 10 , si esta comprendido entre estos 2 te imprime la tabla:

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numero = 0;
    boolean condicion = false;
    while (!condicion) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca un numero entero: ");
        numero = sc.nextInt();
        condicion = (numero <= 10 && numero >= 1);
        if (condicion) {
            System.out.println("Tabla del " + numero);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                System.out.println(numero + " * " + i + " = " + numero * i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
Introduzca un numero entero: 
0
Introduzca un numero entero: 
12
Introduzca un numero entero: 
6
Tabla del 6
6 * 1 = 6
6 * 2 = 12
6 * 3 = 18
6 * 4 = 24
6 * 5 = 30
6 * 6 = 36
6 * 7 = 42
6 * 8 = 48
6 * 9 = 54
6 * 10 = 60
```

Te sugiero revisar lo relacionado a los bucles:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y compartir el link.